# msbuild Directory.Build.props does not work even in very basic example

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have created Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) Solution in Visual Studio 2017 and put following Directory.Build.props file in solution folder.

I have not changed anything except Directory.Build.props. Version of msbuild is 15.9.21.
I confirmed that Directory.Build.pros file is read in msbuild.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <AssemblyFileVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    <Version> 2.0.0.0 </Version>
    <FileVersion> 2.0.0.0 </FileVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In my understanding, version information in AssemblyInfo.cs would be changed, but nothing changed.

What's wrong?

Comment: I totally misunderstood concept of Directory.build.props. It's like default value for Project and Solution. In my example, I have to use Directory.build.targets.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your Directory.Build.Props file. You just need to enable the target that generates AssemblyInfo files automatically:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <AssemblyFileVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    <Version> 2.0.0.0 </Version>
    <FileVersion> 2.0.0.0 </FileVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that when you do this, you will need to remove the AssemblyInfo.cs file from all the projects in your solution, since they will collide with the autogenerated assembly version attributes.